# Retrieve another user view's fetchXml property

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to retrieve a personal view's fetchxml (owned by another user than the one making the requests to the organization service) by doing such:

```
        public static UserQuery RetrieveUserQuery(string userQueryName)
        {

            string xmlFetch = @"<fetch distinct='false' mapping='logical' output-format='xml-platform' version='1.0'> 
                                    <entity name='userquery'>
                                        <attribute name='fetchxml'/>
                                        <filter type='and'>
                                            <condition attribute='name' value='{0}' operator='eq'/>
                                        </filter>
                                    </entity>
                                </fetch>";

            xmlFetch = string.Format(xmlFetch, userQueryName);

            try
            {
                var ent = Helper.XrmProxy.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(xmlFetch));

                if (ent.Entities.Count() == 0)
                    return null;
                if (ent.Entities.Count() > 1)
                    throw new Exception("More than one view with same name found!");

                return ent.Entities[0].ToEntity<UserQuery>();

            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

But it seems we can only do so by using the same credentials on the organization service than the ones owning the view.

Is this really the case ? Is there any bypass ?

This method always returns null (0 entities retrieved). The credentials used on the organization service are System Administrator so I thought I'd have access to it even if it wasn't shared...

Comment: You could potentially audit userquery Create, Update and Delete messages in a Plug-in running on behalf the current user context and save the FetchXml in a custom entity that you can query with ease.

Comment: This is useful although the requirements changed and won't be needing to do this anymore, I'll use system views instead. You could propose it as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personal view is owned only the user made until and unless it is shared with another user. Even the system admin cannot access the personal view of another user